# outer measure of an irrational set

Tags: measure-theory

if $E = [0,1] \bigcap \mathbb{Q}$ to show that the outer measure $m^*(E) = 0 $ , I've used the fact that E is numerable so it can be found the sequence of rationals in E: $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Taken an $\varepsilon >0$ I constructed the intervals: $I_1$ of length $\varepsilon/2$ containing $x_1$, $I_2$ of length  $\varepsilon/4$ containing $x_2$, and so on to have $I_k$ of length $\varepsilon/2^k$  ontaining $x_k$. By the definition of outer measure:

$m^\ast(E):= \inf_P m(P)$

where $P = \bigcup_k I_k$

if my reasoning is right $m^*(E) = 0 $, because $\varepsilon/2^k$ goes to 0 and represents the infimum.

By similar arguments I'd like to obtain the outer measure of the irrationals set $E^c$: $m^*(E^c)$ which I know should be 1, but I am not figuring out how could I cover this set.

Comment: You have posted this question earlier and you have even accepted one of the answers. This makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since $m^*([0,1])=1$ we can use monotonicity to obtain $m^*(E)\leq 1$.

For the other inequality we can use the subadditivity of the outer measure:
$$
 1=m^*([0,1]) \leq m^*(E)+m^*(E^c) = m^*(E^c).
$$